# Why git diff --name-only does not show any modified files?

Tags: git

Please, observe (I am using posh-git):

```
C:\xyz\git [master ↑2 +27 ~0 -0 !]> git diff --name-only
C:\xyz\git [master ↑2 +27 ~0 -0 !]>
```

27 folders are unstaged, each has some files. No changes are staged.

Why does not it show any files?

**EDIT 1**

The following simple transcript demonstrates the problem:

```
C:\xyz> mkdir git


    Directory: C:\xyz


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       10/16/2018   1:20 PM                git


C:\xyz> cd git
C:\xyz\git> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/xyz/git/.git/
C:\xyz\git [master]> echo hello > 1.txt
C:\xyz\git [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git diff --name-only
C:\xyz\git [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        1.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
C:\xyz\git [master +1 ~0 -0 !]>
```

**EDIT 2**

According to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff :

```
git diff [<options>] [--] [<path>…​]
```

> This form is to view the changes
>   you made relative to the index (staging area for the next commit). In
>   other words, the differences are what you could tell Git to further
>   add to the index but you still haven’t. You can stage these changes by
>   using git-add[1].

As far as I understand it means the `git diff --name-only` command in the transcript above should list 1.txt

Comment: Are they being ignored?

Comment: No, otherwise they would not have appeared in the posh-git prompt.

Comment: Are they added already? That would also explain why they are not showing up.

Comment: Added the clarification - no changes are staged.

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: Were the files actually modified regarding their content, or just their line-endings and permission bits? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564946/git-status-shows-changed-files-but-git-diff-doesnt

Comment: Files truly changed and git status shows it. Added additional clarification.

Comment: I would say it's consistent with the way diff behaves by default. If you create a file with a certain content and run git diff, it won't show you that file (cause it's not tracked) so I guess it follows to not display it either if you ask for --name-status

Comment: This is not what the documentation says, at least what it seems to say - see **EDIT 2**

Comment: @mark how about adding the `--no-index` flag?

Comment: `1.txt` is not "modified". It's "untracked".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `git diff` can do a bunch of different things, including (but not limited to):

- compare one commit to another commit
- compare any commit to the index
- compare any commit to the work-tree
- compare the index to the work-tree

As you just noted in your edit, you are selecting this last option.

When you select to compare the index to the work-tree, the list of files to be compared is completely controlled by the index contents.  Any files that are *untracked* are ignored entirely.  This differs from how `git status` compares the index to the work-tree, but saves a lot of time for `git diff` since it does not have to find any files that may be untracked (which in general is a slow operation).

If you want Git to know that the files exist, using an index entry that is a sort of placeholder, consider using `git add --indent-to-add`, or for short, `git add -N` (uppercase N).  I should also mention that this state ("fake-added") was broken for a long time, so there are a number of versions of Git where it behaves weirdly.  It was also [just updated in 2.19 to correct the `git diff` output](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5a0cc8aca797dbd7d2be3b67458ff880ed45cddf/Documentation/RelNotes/2.19.0.txt#L9):

> - "git diff" compares the index and the working tree.  For paths
>     added with intent-to-add bit, the command shows the full contents
>     of them as added, but the paths themselves were not marked as new
>     files.  They are now shown as new by default.