# git diff not working on unstaged changes in tracked files

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two machines, one with git 1.7.0.4, and the other with 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37).

I've modified a file in the tree on each machine (the same change, the same file, but located on two different computers) but have not staged it yet on either.

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Rakefile
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   Hs-At_AND/
```

(The displays are slightly different for the two versions of git. I'm only showing the 1.7.12.4 display.)

On 1.7.12.4 (on my Mac), `git diff Rakefile` shows me the changes in Rakefile relative to the repo version.

But on the other, `git diff Rakefile` does nothing. There's no output, no error message.

There are other similar-*looking* questions on StackOverflow (e.g., [git diff gives no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544211/git-diff-gives-no-output)), but these all seem to be asking about untracked files. My question is regarding tracked-but-not-yet-staged files.

Obviously I'm not doing anything wrong here. What's wrong with my installation, then? Is there something I can change in my `.gitconfig`?

Comment: Are the changes more than just whitespace changes?

Comment: Yes. They are substantive.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's on two different machines, you are possibly running the command on two different physical devices, only one of which contains the changed file.

File changes are machine-local (unless you use a shared/remote file system) until you have committed and pushed changes. Other machines won't see the local changes until they have fetched/pulled the updated repo.

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood the steps to reproduce. I make the same changes to files on both machines. Both repos are cloned from the same original repo. One shows the diff, one doesn't.

Comment: Indeed, I missed where you stated you modified the file on *each* machine.

Comment: I possibly should have made that clearer originally. I just edited to reflect that.