# `git diff`doesn't show changes you have in work tree relative commit

Tags: git

I found that image which graphically show a work of diff command.
[image]

```
git diff HEAD
```

show changes you have in your working tree relative to the HEAD, but if I run this script

```
mkdir test_git
cd test_git
git init
echo 'one_file.txt' >> one_file.txt
git add .
git commit -m "my first commit"
echo 'second_file.txt' >> second_file.txt
git diff HEAD
```

then diff don't show diff of seconrd_file.txt. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8544211/1030675

Answer (score 1):

The `git diff` command provides the relative difference between the current working directory or current index with respect to `HEAD`. In your example above you are creating a new file but have not added it to the index or committed it. In terms of `HEAD` the new file does not exist and is not tracked so there is no difference. Staging the file in the index with `git add second_file.txt` would introduce the new file to the repository and would yield a diff when executing `git diff --cached` command.

The process of tracking changes is explained in detail in the freely available in [Pro Git - 2.2 Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).