# Nothing but \copyright returns outputs in psql interface

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have successfully logged in a PostgreSQL database with `psql -d <name> -h <IP address> -U <user name>`. However, commands like `\d` and queries like `SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 5;` return nothing without errors, but only `\copyright` returns the paragraph. Even `\?` and `\h` give me nothing. I am pretty sure that this database is not empty because I can retrieve information with the same logins and queries with `pandas.read_sql` in Python and `RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery` in R. Hence it should be problems in `psql`.

My wild guess is this might be a [similar problem of pager when executing `git diff`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544211/git-diff-gives-no-output/23281815#23281815) as I just fixed that a few days ago. Is it possible? If so, how can I change the pager settings? If not, what can be reasons causing the situation and how to fix it?

The information of OS and PostgreSQL are listed below:

> Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
>   psql (10.1, server 9.4.15)

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the db?  Run \c <Your Database Name> .

Comment: Following you can run \dt to list the database tables.

Comment: @Gerik `\c <my database name>` returns _You are now connected to database "<my database name>" as user "<my user name>"._, while `\dt` returns nothing.

Comment: I might suspect you don't have permission to access anything in the database, you're not connecting to the correct database, or the db is just empty.

Comment: @Gerik thanks but I think the situations you mentioned are rather unlikely. First, this database is password-protected so I must enter the correct password and other login information to get the connection, and there's not a login failure. Second, like I said in the question, I can retrieve tables in Python and R environments, so I do have permissions to the database and the database is not empty. BTW neither `\h` nor `\?` is working, and this should not be a permission-related problem.

Comment: [\pset pager off](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) or `\setenv pager` or [the page environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-ENVIRONMENT)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that does the trick. Thank you.